# Scheduling an event not executing

Tags: mysql, events

I am testing my mysql database and currently using dbforge IDE. When I create an event, for accessing some values from a table, which is supposed to occur after sometime, but it's not running and I don't get an error either. Please let me know exactly how to schedule an event in dbforge properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default event scheduler is disabled try check whether it is on or not.

`show variables like 'event_scheduler';`

Comment: Dear James ... you are right event scheduler was disable by default. I enabled it by connecting to mysql using command prompt and setting it as "set global event_scheduler=on;"

Comment: Good. So it concludes your concern has been solved.

Comment: Just Upvote and then mark this as answer to close this question.

Comment: I tired to mark that answer but my marking is not counting :)

Comment: Okay, its due to low reputation. anyways no problem.But you can accept this as answer by clicking the "Tick Mark" next to the arrows.